# How to get distinct values in mongodb aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to to get distinct values in mongodb. I am using mongodb aggregation. How to use distinct in aggregation query. I am using it in node.js

below is my query in model

```
const criteria = [
        { $match: { $and: [{ $text: { $search: search } }, { $or: [publicData, { $and: [publisherId, { $or: [unListedData, privateData] }] }] }] } },
        { $lookup: { from: 'user', localField: 'userId', foreignField: 'id', as: 'publisherDetails' } },
        { $addToSet: '$_id' },
        { $sort: { created_at: -1 } }
];
```

Here I have used `$addToset`, but it did not work.
I have followed the doc's

[distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/distinct/),
[addToset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet), 
but still coud not get proper solution

Comment: [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) says it's only available in `$group` stage

Comment: yes but I dont want to use `$group`. I just want to display distinct values.. Now some id's are repeating

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Can you post some sample data and a matching sample of the desired output of your query?

Comment: @Ashraf to get distinct values using aggregation, you **need** to use $group. The distinct method you mentioned is not part of the aggregation framework. It's a separate command.

Comment: can you apply `$group` and distinct to my above query and show me..